# GTK# projects in Visual Studio 2015/Xamarin Studio missing

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, gtk#

I am planning to create cross-plateform GUI Application (for linux/windows).
I first try to create GTK# project in Xamarin Studio with success.
But now as a Software Engineer with an MSDN subscription I wanted to create GTK# project in VS2015.

My problem is that I have done a full install od VS2015 and Xamarin Stuudio Plugin and I still don't see the GTK# project template on the "New Project Wizard".

Can someone confirm that we can do that?

Subsidiary question: is the gui designer of GTK# windows fully integrated in VS2015 with Xamarin extensions?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to create GTK# projects in Visual Studio after installing Xamarin. You can, however, create GTK# projects in Xamarin Studio for Windows.

Comment: Do you mean  : "it is only possible to create GTK# projects in Visual Studio" only if you don't have installed Xamarin Studio as standalone application ?

Comment: Visual Studio doesn't have the designers for GTK# that MonoDevelop (Xamarin Studio) does. You can develop GTK# in VS just you'd have to do it all yourself, rather than use the designers, which you would have to be super keen to be using VS to put up with. You're better off using MD if you want to use GTK#.

Comment: VS has no templates for creating GTK# projects, so as @muszeo said, it's better to use XS/MD.